# How to get process serial number of current running process

Tags: xcode, process, deprecated, nsapplication

In OS X 10.9 and below, we can get the process serial number of the current running process with:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn;
GetCurrentProcess(&psn);
```

However, `GetCurrentProcess()` is now deprecated and I’m unsure how to find a process’ serial number with `NSRunningApplication`.

Comment: Maybe check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24545462/5941807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get ProcessSerialNumber you can use:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn;
psn.highLongOfPSN = 0;
psn.lowLongOfPSN = kCurrentProcess;
```